# Comparing Dates from custom field

Tags: php, custom-field, date-time

I am trying to compare dates from a custom field. I have them stored as something like "20121125". If the date has expired, a placeholder image will be used, if not, the default thumbnail will be used. Any advice is appreciated.

```
<?php
$html = "";
$key = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Due', true);
$date = date('ymd');
if ($key >= $date) {
     the_post_thumbnail('medium');
} else {
    $html .= '<img src="http://exampleimage.com" alt="">';
}
return $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the exact server time/timestamp can be retrieve with current_time function. And comparing your date format, it would need to be Ymd. So combining these two thing, the proper comparison for you should be -

```
$key = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Due', true );
$date = date('Ymd', current_time('timestamp') );

if( $key >= $date )
{
    // note to retrive the post thumbnail, you need to use get_the_post_thumbnail,
    // as the_post_thumbnail function actually echo the output
    $html .= get_the_post_thumbnail(null, 'medium');
}
else 
{
    $html .= '<img src="http://exampleimage.com" alt="">';
}
return $html;
```

Now, there could be one question in which timezone you are saving the date in the post meta. If the value is sanitized with the server time (as the post_date value is saved), then this is perfect comparison.

Comment: This looks great, but I think I have something wrong with my return $html; ... all the content is pushed to the left on my site and other info is just no there. Any idea? :)

Comment: Well, without seeing you complete code, and where you are actually using it, it's hard to tell. If you are using this within a function, then it should be fine for each loop, but if u are using this within the template file, then there shouldn't be 'return $html' as this will stop all the next PHP processing and templates ex footer/sidebar. Can you be a little more specific ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I did, I have it in a template file and the next bit of php is not parsing :( ..... see http://hastebin.com/pisonufoje.php

Comment: You need to echo it actually, instead of `return $html;` , use `echo $html;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php
$html = "";
$key = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Due', true);
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos'); //Only if needed. Change this for your timezone
if (strtotime($key) >= time()) {
     the_post_thumbnail('medium');
} else {
    $html .= '<img src="http://exampleimage.com" alt="">';
}
return $html;
?>
```

Here we are using the strtotime function to help us compare these two dates.

You can find more information here:

- [Comparing dates in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722806/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-php)
- [Change the default timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765158/date-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings-in-codeigniter)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the date after coonverting to timestamp using custom fields(i.e. in post_meta table). By doing so you will be able to compare dates easily. Then you can use your code as follows:

```
<?php
$html = "";
$stored_timestamp = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Due', true);
$current_timestamp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
if ($stored_timestamp >= $current_timestamp) {
    the_post_thumbnail('medium');
} else {
    $html .= '<img src="http://exampleimage.com" alt="">';
}
return $html;
?>
```

Store timestamp as:

```
update_post_meta($post->ID,'Due',strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
```